# Spacemacs+magit+helm checkout hide branches

Tags: spacemacs, magit, helm, filtering

Due to my workflow I have a lot of branches that I don't want to see in the magit helm checkout window. Is there a way to hide some branches here, preferably with a regexp?

Comment: On the Magit end, there isn't a user option for something like this.
You don't give the details of your workflow, but if the branches of
interest tend to be the most recently modified ones,
using `(setq magit-list-refs-sortby "-creatordate")` could help.

Comment: Does this satisfy your needs?

Comment: No, I need filtering by regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Magit does not support this currently. You should open a feature request. I probably won't implement this any time soon, but an issue would help me to not forget about this completely.

Edit: I am longer considering to implement this. My recommendation is to set `remote.<name>.fetch` so that the boring branches don't even make it into your local repository.

---

You can however abuse another feature that I just added for this purpose:

```
(advice-add 'magit-list-branch-names :around
            #'magit-list-branch-names:filter)

(defun magit-list-branch-names:filter (fn)
  (-filter #'magit-refs-insert-refname-p (funcall fn)))
```

You will have to advice other `magit-list-*` functions the same way for all commands to be affected. And obviously you have to customize `magit-refs-filter-alist`.

---

Another option could be to use a completion framework (such as `ivy`) that let you easily deal with many completion candidates.